# prioritizing okhttp async requests

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I need to prioritize queued okhttp async requests; what's the recommended way of doing this; passing a custom [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to the [Dispatcher](http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/Dispatcher.html)?

It'd be nice to prioritize the requests *before* they're executed by the ExecutorService, but it looks like there's no way to customize Dispatcher's internal [readyCalls](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/Dispatcher.java#L44) Deque, and Dispatcher itself is final (and [OkHttpClient.setDispatcher()](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.java#L426) only takes a Dispatcher, i.e. not an interface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're tracking this as [Issue 404](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/404). If you make your request known there, we'll know to prioritize it accordingly!